# displaying div through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I have the following code:-

`document.getElementById(id2).style.display="none";
document.getElementById("legislate").style.display="block";
$scope.getLegislatorDetails(bio);
document.getElementById("ind_legislator").style.display="block";`

I just want the div ind_legislator to be displayed when this function is called. But the ind_legislator div is inside the legislate div. So if I used just `document.getElementById("ind_legislator").style.display="block";`
then its does not appear in the browser but if I use the above then only its content are visible. But I dont want the content of the legislate div. How can this be done???

Comment: So, you want to show an inner element, but not its wrapper? Not possible, bring the inner element out of the wrapper.